# Compiler options warnings vs linter

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.12 is there any difference between any of these options:

- `-Xlint:adapted-args` vs `-Ywarn-adapted-args`
- `-Xlint:nullary-unit` vs `-Ywarn-nullary-unit`
- `-Xlint:inaccessible` vs `-Ywarn-inaccessible`
- `-Xlint:nullary-override` vs `-Ywarn-nullary-override`
- `-Xlint:infer-any` vs `-Ywarn-infer-any`

If not, which one makes more sense to use? I also compile with `fatal-warnings`, and almost all `-Ywarn` and `-Xlint` options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `scalac -Xlint:help` you'll see

```
❯ scalac -Xlint:help
Enable or disable specific warnings
  adapted-args               Warn if an argument list is modified to match the receiver.
  nullary-unit               Warn when nullary methods return Unit.
  inaccessible               Warn about inaccessible types in method signatures.
  nullary-override           Warn when non-nullary `def f()' overrides nullary `def f'.
  infer-any                  Warn when a type argument is inferred to be `Any`.
  missing-interpolator       A string literal appears to be missing an interpolator id.
  doc-detached               A Scaladoc comment appears to be detached from its element.
  private-shadow             A private field (or class parameter) shadows a superclass field.
  type-parameter-shadow      A local type parameter shadows a type already in scope.
  poly-implicit-overload     Parameterized overloaded implicit methods are not visible as viewbounds.
  option-implicit            Option.apply used implicit view.
  delayedinit-select         Selecting member of DelayedInit.
  by-name-right-associative  By-name parameter of right associative operator.
  package-object-classes     Class or object defined in package object.
  unsound-match              Pattern match may not be typesafe.
  stars-align                Pattern sequence wildcard must align with sequence component.
  constant                   Evaluation of a constant arithmetic expression results in an error.
  unused                     Enable -Ywarn-unused:imports,privates,locals,implicits.
Default: All choices are enabled by default.
```

so there's no difference between selecting `Xlint` options or using the corresponding flags directly. I would just go with `-Xlint` (no options, so all enabled by default) and remove the ones I don't need, for example

`-Xlint:-unused,_`

to enable everything but the `unused` flag.

Comment: That is certainly a better approach to what I was doing. However it does not explain what are the differences between "using" the options via the linter or via warnings, are they exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, those are exactly the same options, just enabled by different flags

Comment: Note that `-Xlint` compiler option is not supported by Scala 3, and will cause a fatal JVM error. https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/replacement-for-xlint-in-scala3/5241